# Задача с тремя переменными, какой код необходимо прописать?

Tags: javascript

В программе заданы три переменные name, last_name, age, в которых хранятся имя, фамилия и возраст пользователя соответственно. Сформируйте объект с ключами name, last_name, age и значениями из соответствующих переменных. Выведите этот объект в консоль.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
let name = "Fill";
let age = 45;
let lastName = "Jordan";

let obj = {
    name: name,
    age: age,
    lastName: lastName
};

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score -3):

```
fn main() {
    
    let user1 = User{
        name:"Andrey".to_string(),
        last_name:"Ivanov".to_string(),
        age:26
    };

    User::get_user(user1.name, user1.last_name, user1.age);
}

struct User{
    name: String,
    last_name: String,
    age: i32
}

impl User {
    fn get_user(name:String ,last_name:String,age:i32) {
        println!("Hello {name} {last_name}. Are you years {age} old")
    }
}
```

Реализация на Rust

Comment: Как реализовать в JS?